# wpf storyboard animation lasts only 2 seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have a WPF application which contains a an ellipse which has a circular animation. The animation only runs for 2 seconds and I would like it to run until I tell the storyboard to stop.

This is the Resource Dictionary Storyboard Definition:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="AnimateCircle" Duration="00:05:00">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="{Binding}">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF212121"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="{Binding}">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFF7F4F5"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="{Binding}" Duration="00:05:00">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="359"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

This is my WPF XAML code:

```
            <Ellipse 
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                x:Name="AnimationCircle" 
                Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                Height="200" Width="200"
                StrokeThickness="30" 
                Visibility="Visible"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <Ellipse.Stroke>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF212121" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF7F4F5" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.Stroke>
            </Ellipse>
```

This is WPF C# Code behind to start the animation:

```
sb = this.FindResource("AnimateCircle") as Storyboard;
Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, AnimationCircle);
sb.Begin(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete `Duration="00:05:00"` from Storyboard and modify `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`  like this

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="{Binding}"  RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="359"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```